# How to fix non-repeating sent emails from Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to send emails from google sheets and for it to populate a column when sent, once it's sent and populated that column I'd like it to register that the email has been sent and then not email that person again

Here is the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f6qUjGYHZtRRGCbyh5oNzM7o64B-wlkrTpB1ac64I2U/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried different code that works when I use the sample code but can't seem to get mine to work

```
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
function sendEmailsZ() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 4; 
  var numRows = 2; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("J4:K5");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; 
    var message = row[1]; 
    var emailSent = row[2]; 
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { 
      var subject = 'Non Repeat B08 - populates correct column but doesnt prevent re-sending';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 12).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

This sends the desired messages to the desired email addresses and populates the "Email Sent" column in the right place however when I run the script again it ignores the "EMAIL_SENT" command and re-sends the email despite the column being filled in

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function sendEmailsZ() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 4; 
  var numRows = 2; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(4,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; 
    var message = row[1]; 
    var emailSent = row[2];//You were not getting this data because your range was incorrect 
     var subject = 'Non Repeat B08 - populates correct column but doesnt prevent re-sending';
    if (emailAddress && message && subject && emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT') { 
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 12).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you! I then tried to change L5 to L100 however presumably because there were no email addresses beyond J5 the script would not run. Is there a way to overcome this? Essentially the email column would be populated overtime and I would not like to edit the script each time when new emails have been updated

Comment: Sure I’ll take a look at your spreadsheet and get back with you

Comment: Thanks again Cooper, that produced an error that says "Failed to send email: no recipient (line 15, file "filename"). That line was previously var dataRange = sheet.getRange("J4:L5");